# Font selection utitly

Tags: windows, font-utility

Is there any good software to help in choosing a font? I don't mean only a font manager, but a tool that helps comparing local fonts. It would also be very useful if the software can filter list of font base on the availability of some glyphs.

Comment: Related, but more specific: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16808/is-there-a-professional-grade-cross-platform-font-manager

Answer (score 3):

> It would also be very useful if the software can filter list of font
>   base on the availability of some glyphs.

There are some good tools for this, but difficult to find. [Alan Wood’s Unicode resources](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/) is almost too comprehensive. When you need something Unicode (like glyphs), that is a good place to start.

[BabelMap](http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html) (Unicode Character Map for Windows) is crazy powerful. Your specific request, above, is simple. Find the glyph you like. In the menu bar, click Fonts/Font Coverage..., choose your option (if you are just looking for one glyph, then the top option), and click Calculate Font Coverage. It will show your installed fonts with the glyph. It can also load fonts that are not installed and search those.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this way if I want to know particular font style of any website

I go to **developer mode** in chrome and click on any text and in the **computed** tab go to Rendered Font which show the font style applied (e.g **Arial – 241 Glyphs**)

Answer (score 0):

My answer is proposing two tools (and personally I am using even more):

**Firstly**

"fontmatrix" has a dedicated classification tab, where you can search or compare "family type", "serif style", "weight", "proportion", and six more criteria in an amazing visual web.

There is also a dedicated "compare" tab for the glyphs. And of course such features as sample texts and powerful search through all fonts on your machine (installed and otherwise).

[As fontmatrix seems to be a no-longer-active project I am giving here one of the download sites uptodown.com - 0.6 is the last version I could find, please advise a link if you find a later version.](https://fontmatrix.en.uptodown.com/windows)

**Secondly**

If your main concern is for fonts which carry certain (to you) important glyphs, there are special tools. I wrote something in another forum:
[Character Identifier tool](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/69843/48388)